# How do I know which prerequisites my application needs?

Tags: c#, .net, prerequisites

So I wrote an application and created an installer. When I tried to install it on other machines, the app simply wouldn't work. After messing around with it for a while, it seemed like I needed to select visual C++ Runtime Libraries as a prerequisite. Now I'm wondering if I may need other prereqs. How on earth do I know what are all the prereqs an app will need?

Comment: Well you built the application, so you know what technologies you are using. So you could search online what are the dlls or things that have to be installed in the client machine when you deploy an App. Your question is too general and I think it depends a lot on what technology you are working on. Maybe give more details of your applications?

Comment: It's going to depend on what you coded it in.  Do you use .net?  You'll probably need the re-distributable installed.  Did you use WCF and are installing the app on a customers web server?  You'll probably need to install the WCF re-dstributable and have them enable WPA in programs and features.  If you have a specific question, I would add it to your post so we can help you better.

Comment: C#, .Net 4, and I'm also using powrprof.dll and kernel32.dll. It seems that using these .dll is what requires that any machine running this app has the visual C++ runtime installed. Granted, I'm still learning, I'm know to windows programming (I'm coming in from the Android world). I tried looking up those .dll but didn't find anything that indicated this run time would be needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create setup file for c# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976670/how-can-i-create-setup-file-for-c-sharp-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the dependencies of a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application)